# Testing Rails with Postgres database suddenly fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

In a Rails project that uses a Postgres database, I use rspec for testing. This worked fine until I added another migration. Now rspec fails with:

```
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

PG::ConnectionBad:
connection is closed
```

I have tried to prepare the test database in various ways:

```sh
rails db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
rails db:prepare RAILS_ENV=test
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

and also

```sh
rails db:test:prepare
```

My tests used to work until I added the migration, so clearly something has gone foul, but what?

---

Edited to add more detail:

While the Postgres logs were not revealing at all, I did find out the following:

The error occurs at this line in `rails_helper.rb`:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

From the Rails console in the `test` environment, I can call the `maintain_test_schema!` method without problems:

```rb
root@0bf32217fb90:/home/dora/rails# bin/rails c -e test
Loading test environment (Rails 6.0.3.4)
[1] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
(1.2ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", "schema_sha1"]]
(1.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
=> nil
[2] pry(main)>
```

So evidently there is a difference between calling the method from `rspec` and calling it from the console.

I'll keep this updated for others to say, and if someone tumbles upon this and knows the solution, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Try looking in your postgresql logs.

Comment: The logs did not contain anything revealing, just a few statements with regards to the current time zone. I have updated my question with additional information. Evidently, the error occurs only in a given context.

Comment: I met same issue after upgrading my application from Rails 5.2 to 6.0. Have you found a fix? Thanks.

Comment: @AndyWang Unfortnuately not. I commented out the block that calls `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` in `spec_helper.rb`, which lets me run the tests, but I don't consier this a fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met same issue after upgrading my rails app from 5.2 to 6.0. Finally I fixed it and the details are at [PG::ConnectionBad(connection is closed) when running rspec after upgrading application from Rails 5.2 to 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299580/pgconnectionbadconnection-is-closed-when-running-rspec-after-upgrading-appli/66301349#66301349) . You should check if there are any rspec supporters overrides the creation of dB connections

Comment: Excellent! Would never have thought of old cruft in a support directory being the cause... As advised, I had to remove `spec/support/shared_db_connection.rb` which is not a genuine Rails file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after many hours pulling my hair out, I've found that we need to replace all `require 'rails_helper` by `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of each spec.